# Could you please tell me what's wrong this javascript code

Tags: javascript, calculator

This code is supposed to calculate the sum, substract, multiply, divide at the same time when the user types in x and y but it's showing Nan

```js
function perform(x, y) {
  x = prompt("enter first no. ")
  y = prompt(" enter second no. ")

  function sum(x, y) {
    console.log(parseInt(x + y));
  }

  sum();

  function minus(x, y) {
    console.log(parseInt(x - y));
  }

  minus();

  function multiply(x, y) {
    console.log(parseInt(x * y));
  }

  multiply();
  
  function divide(x, y) {
    console.log(parseInt(x / y));
  }

  divide();
}
```

Comment: prompt will give you a string and not a number, `NaN` means "not a number".

Comment: Use parseInt for x and y

Comment: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Your function expects argument, which you don't pass when you call the functions.

Answer (score 1):

`prompt` will return `A string containing the text entered by the user, or null.` as stated in the mdn docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

So instead of `parseInt(x - y)` you should first parse each input into a integer (or float) and then do the addition, multiplication etc.

```js
(function perform() {
  const x = parseInt(prompt("enter first no. "))
  const y = parseInt(prompt("enter second no. "))

  sum(x, y);
  minus(x, y);
  multiply(x, y);
  divide(x, y);
})();

function sum(x, y) {
  console.log(x + y);
}

function minus(x, y) {
  console.log(x - y);
}

function divide(x, y) {
  console.log(x / y);
}

function multiply(x, y) {
  console.log(x * y);
}
```

and please read the so link commented by @Ivar

Answer (score -1):

Both X and Y are strings, when entered via the prompt dialog. You need to parse them separately before adding them, e.g.:

```
function sum(x, y) {
    console.log(parseInt(x) + parseInt(y));
}
```

In addition, you are calling all the methods without providing the variable inputs, so instead of `sum()`, you should call `sum(x,y)`